# Addition of long values show different o/p

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I am facing problem in doing addition of long values 
example

```
 typedef unsigned short  UINT16;

   UINT16* flash_dest_ptr;  // this is equal to in hexa 0XFF910000

   UINT16 data_length ; // hex =  0x000002AA &  dec = 682

  //now when I add  

  UINT16 *memory_loc_ver = flash_dest_ptr + data_length ;

  dbug_printf( DBUG_ERROR | DBUG_NAVD, " ADD hex =0x%08X\n\r",memory_loc_ver   );
```

Actual O/p  = 0xFF910554

```
// shouldn't o/p be FF9102AA ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pointer arithmetic, so

```
UINT16 *memory_loc_ver = flash_dest_ptr + data_length ;
```

advances `flash_dest_ptr` by `data_length * sizeof (UINT16)` bytes.

Typically, `sizeof (UINT16)` would be 2, and

```
2 * 0x2AA = 0x554
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, and Colin for the help

Answer (score 0):

When you add integers to a pointer value, you are actually moving the pointer as many bytes as it would take to move `data_length` `UINT16`s away in memory, not `data_length` bytes.